# Transition in Spark Components like BorderContainer, List, etc.,

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, adobe, flash-builder4.5

I am developing flex mobile project in adobe air, using flash builder 4.7, i am able to apply Transition in views, How can i apply Transition to Spark components like BorderContainer, List...

```
<s:BorderContainer id="Login" backgroundAlpha="0" borderStyle="inset" visible="true" >
<s:Label width="100%" height="100%" color="white" text="Logon Details"/>
<s:TextArea prompt="UserName" id="txtuser" />
<s:TextArea prompt="Password" id="txtpwd" />            
<s:CheckBox />
<s:Button id="btnlogin" color="white" fontFamily="Book Antiqua" fontWeight="bold"/>
<s:Button id="btnreset" color="white" fontFamily="Book Antiqua" fontWeight="bold"/>
</s:BorderContainer>
```

I would like to apply Transition for above BorderContainer, like moving BorderContainer to  another location in screen on clicking a button.
Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a little code to show you how to use a `Tween` manually, without a `Transition`.

```
<fx:Declarations>
   <mx:Move id="myMove" target="{login}" xTo="200" yTo="500"/>
</fx:Declarations>

<s:Group width="100%" height="100%">
    <s:BorderContainer id="login" />
</s:Group>

<s:Button id="button" click="myMove.play(); button.enabled=false;" />
```

You may find, for each `Tween`, some code example in the reference, such as [this one](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/effects/Move.html#includeExamplesSummary).